Is my lead acid charging circuit fine?
I would like to ask for review in my schematic circuit for charging lead acid battery with following data:
6 cells per unit (1.75 V per cell), float charging voltage between 13.7-13.9 V, maximum charging current 0.69 A.
My schematic:

First part is voltage divider. Second part is using comparator to connect 13.8 V node to charge battery if battery voltage is below 13 V. Disconnect 13.8 V above 13.5 V. I rather disconnect earlier to prevent overcharing.
Third part is connection to main circuit.
Is my design alright? I am not so sure about my voltage divider. If U14 MOSFET goes on then I think voltage divider will result into 6.9 V (13.8 V from charging node / 2). Or am I wrong, can you explain why will voltage divider remains real battery voltage?
EDIT: Based on comments, 13.8V is providing max 2A. In this circuit current limit is not yet implemented as that will be my next step.
EDIT2: Edits based on @KevinWhite feedback


You will never reach 100 % SoC with this, but that’s perhaps not your goal? How do you limit the charge current?

Something has to limit the current into the battery to a safe value.  What is the max current available from the 13.8 V source, and what is the max charging current specification for the battery?  Please add this information to the question.

@winny I am avarage Im not reaching 100% battery, thats not goal, because i need to power two devices with 13.8V. Limiting current is not right now implemented yet. That will be my next step.

@AnalogKid max current is right now 2A. Current limit is not yet implemented, I am aware of it that I have to implement it. That will be next step.

There are numerous errors in the circuit: why D6, LM393 is open collector, MOSFETs backwards, don't forget about body diodes. What is CHARGE voltage levels.

@KevinWhite I though adding D6 would prevent 13.8V node from incorrect values on voltage divider, you saying I should remove it? CHARGE is controlled by MCU to get correct voltage values by disconnecting it from charger for few ms to read values. Can you explain more LM393 is open collector / MOSFET backwards? I followed other design where MOSFETs should be this way. Whats wrong on them right now?

I would start with the current limit.

D6 is reverse biased - it will prevent any current flowing in the current divider. Remove it. You have the source of the FETs to the battery, it should connect to 13.8V.

LM393 needs a pull-up to 13.8v. The signal "CHARGE" needs to swing between ground and 13.8V to turn on/turn off Q3 - you won't get that directly from a MCU.

@KevinWhite thanks for feedback. I added to original post updated schematic. I also tried to run it via https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html seems okay now. I never thought MCU signal was not enought to turn on Q3. Do you see any other mistakes I made to recently updated schematic?

You need a resistor in series with the base of Q8 - as shown it would be driven with 100s of milliamps (depending on the gain of Q7. It doesn't need to be a Darlington either. R41 should be a bit lower, and R34 higher - there is excessive hysteresis.

The circuit is not fine.
Imagine the battery has gotten empty and voltage is 12.00V. When you plug it in, your circuit will connect 13.8V supply voltage to it, and something will blow up. The battery can draw tens of amps and the supply and components must handle that without blowing up. You cannot connect a battery to a voltage supply. Not without the actual charging circuit that limits the curren to safe level, if you want to implement CC-CV charging.

Whats your recommendation for building current limit? DC-DC converter?

@user1085907 If a DC-DC converter allows you to build a CC-CV charger then yes. There may exist all-in-one lead-acid charging ICs that implement all the intricacies of charging batteries for you, such as trickle charging befoe applying full charge and then the topping up and floating phases if you intend to keep the charger connected to battery all the time. So it depends how fancy charger you need. If you just need charging a lab power supply is the simplest CC-CV charger which you need to disconnect yourself when full.

I tried to find lead-acid charging IC but they are too far expensive vs li-ion charging ICs.

@user1085907 Have you seen MP2659 Reference Design: 12V Lead-Acid Battery Charging Solution? There are probably lots of similar solutions from other manufacturers.
